# preference-v14 ListPreference uses the default color for the radio buttons

Tags: android, android-preference-v14, support-preference

I'm using the preferences-v14 support library.

When I use `ListPreference`, the radio buttons are colored not according to the accent color of my theme (when running on Android 5.1).

When in Android 4.1, the radio buttons become black.

How to make the radio buttons follow the accent color of the theme?

[image: wrong color]

Answer (score 0):

Try to define in the style.xml the following style:

```
<style name="AppPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrefCat</item>
</style>
```

It should help you to change the color.